# I dont understand "instance has not been initialized" on MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm studying MVVM on Example.
I dont understand why not initialized although I initialized the variable 'instance'
Please let me know...
when I log the var instance in getInstance(), it seems to not be called when I call. and the error code 
"lateinit property mNicePlaces has not been initialized"
I guess the problem is here

```
    fun getInstance(): NicePlaceRepository {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = NicePlaceRepository()
        }
        Log.d("TAG","11111")
        return instance
    }
```

but I initialized that instance by singleton... why it is not called? what should I do for this?

ViewModel

```
private lateinit var mNicePlaces :MutableLiveData<List<NicePlace>>
lateinit var mRepository : NicePlaceRepository

fun init(){
    if(mNicePlaces!=null) return
    mRepository =  NicePlaceRepository().getInstance()
    mNicePlaces = mRepository.getNicePlaces()
}

fun getNicePlaces():LiveData<List<NicePlace>>{
    return mNicePlaces
}
```

Repository

```
private val dataSet = ArrayList<NicePlace>()
companion object {
    lateinit var instance: NicePlaceRepository
}

fun getInstance(): NicePlaceRepository {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = NicePlaceRepository()
    }
    Log.d("TAG","11111")
    return instance
}
fun getNicePlaces():MutableLiveData<List<NicePlace>>{
    setNicePlaces()
   var data = MutableLiveData<List<NicePlace>>()
   data.value = dataSet
   return data
}
private fun setNicePlaces(){
    for(i:Int in 0..5){
        dataSet.add(NicePlace("111", "111"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declared `lateinit var instance: NicePlaceRepository`, this instance cannot be null. And your check `if (instance == null)` won't pass, and instance won't be initiated.

One way to solve is by checking whether lateinit instance is initialised or not instead of null check. Or make the instance nullable:

Change this,

```
lateinit var instance: NicePlaceRepository
```

to:

```
 var instance: NicePlaceRepository? = null
```

Also, you have to add double bangs for instance in getInstance() method:

```
fun getInstance(): NicePlaceRepository {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = NicePlaceRepository()
    }
    Log.d("TAG","11111")
    return instance!!
}
```

Comment: If it's working, could you update this answer as right?

Comment: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok~~~~~~ I did.